# Nginx replace // with / in URL

Tags: nginx

We are currently getting web requests with www.domain.com//index.php which are resolving, but causing issues with google. How can we rewrite the request to catch these and redirect to www.domain.com/index.php

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ngingx merges double-slashes and urls like www.domain.com//index.php works well.

You can turn off merging and make rewrite rule with redirection:

```
merge_slashes off;
rewrite (.*)//(.*) $1/$2 permanent;
```